# Title based on input

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm trying to create a title based on the input symbol received in SYM1.

```
//@version=4
res2 = input(type=input.resolution, defval="5", title="2nd resolution")
SYM1 = input(type=input.symbol, defval="ESCORTS", title="SYMBOL 1")

symbch1 = security(SYM1, res2, high[1],  barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(symbch1, title={{SYM1}} & "Prev Day High", style=plot.style_line, color=color.black, linewidth=1, trackprice=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Titles have to be constants unfortunately.